# MySQLdump no data export

Tags: database, mysql

I want to do a mysqldump with the table definition and table data every day, for this I config a cron job with this comand: "mysqldump -u user -pxxxxx site_DB | gzip > backup/site/site_t_$(date | awk {'print $1"*"$2"*"$3"_"$4'}).sql.gz" but this only export the table definition.  What is the correct command to export the data? Thanks

Comment: As far as I can see, this should export the full data, at least as far as the mysqldump call goes. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump.html

Answer (score 10):

By default [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump.html) exports data too - you have to use the --no-data flag to make it only export structure. Since yours IS doing it by default, that means "no-data" is set in your a MySQL [options file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/option-files.html), which you can find following [these directions](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,295065).

Comment: Can I suggest you reproduce the line in my*.cnf that forces the no-data option?  Struggling to find it.  Neither link contains a "no-data" option

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. re-run the dump command with '--databases' as follows:

```
mysqldump -u user -pxxxxx --databases site_DB . . . .
```